# PHP vs .NET JSON web service

Tags: .net, asp.net, iphone, wcf, json

My iPhone app communicates with a RESTful service that provides JSON output.  I've been generating JSON using mainly PHP.  If I use a .NET web service or WCF service, will there be any limitations or differences I should be aware of in regards to JSON as input/output for the service?  I'm not sure what to expect from .NET in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed: 
.NET emits DateTime objects as

```
 \/Date(xxxx)\/
```

where xxx is the number of seconds or whatever. I had to eval that on the JAvascript side to get it to become an actual date.

Comment: Thanks.  Other than the date, you believe there probably isn't much to be concerned about?

Comment: JSON is just JSON, right?  Have you ever written a WCF service? That's probably the biggest hurdle.

Comment: see this example for a good start on a basic WCF service that emits JSON
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/wcf-how-do-i-return-clean-json/

Comment: Thanks.  That's a very good resource.  Do you know of any issues on the input side?  Meaning, am I OK to send JSON to the WCF service without having to do anything special?

Comment: No special requirements on the input side. You can send complex objects to WCF, too. For some suggestions on that, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062053/passing-complex-objects-into-a-wcf-rest-service/2062143#2062143