# What to type in browser's url to pass an object to webservice

Tags: wcf

Is there a way to enter the url in browser in such a way that it also has the object needed as argument of a wcf webservice? In easy words. I've a webservice's operation contract which receives an object. What url should I type in browser to call that function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've a webservice's operation contract which receives an object. What
>   url should I type in browser to call that function?

NO, that's wrong way of doing it; instead have your operation accepts the object as argument and pass it while calling it like

```
[OperationContract]
public void Operation1(Student stu) { ... };
```

While calling

```
Student stu = new Student();
wcfproxy.Operation1(stu);
```

This post may help

[Passing complex objects into a WCF Rest Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062053/passing-complex-objects-into-a-wcf-rest-service)

Comment: I know that. But I want to know if I want to do it in url. Can I. If yes how?

Comment: okay. And what to do if the client is an android application? what code is needed?

Comment: So the link you gave me. Means there is no other way like typing in the url manually in browser. Right?