# Passing a class as parameter in RESTful WCF Service

Tags: wcf, rest, service, uritemplate

In my RESTful WCF Serice I need to pass a class as a parameter for URITemplate.
I was able to pass a string or multiple strings as parameters. 
But I have a lot of fields are there to pass to WCF Service.
So I have created a class and added all the fields as properties and then
I want to pass this class as one paramenter to the URITemplate.
When I am trying to pass class to the URITemplate I am getting error 
"Path segment must have type string". Its not accepting class as a parameter.
Any idea how to pass class as a parameter.
Here is my code (inputData is class)

---

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/InsertData/{param1}")]
    string saveData(inputData param1);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You actually can pass a complex type (class) in a GET request, but you need to "teach" WCF how to use it, via a QueryStringConverter. However, you usually **shouldn't** do that, especially in a method which will change something in the service (GET should be for read-only operations).

The code below shows both passing a complex type in a GET (with a custom QueryStringConverter) and POST (the way it's supposed to be done).

```
public class StackOverflow_6783264
{
    public class InputData
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/InsertData?param1={param1}")]
        string saveDataGet(InputData param1);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/InsertData")]
        string saveDataPost(InputData param1);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string saveDataGet(InputData param1)
        {
            return "Via GET: " + param1.FirstName + " " + param1.LastName;
        }
        public string saveDataPost(InputData param1)
        {
            return "Via POST: " + param1.FirstName + " " + param1.LastName;
        }
    }
    public class MyQueryStringConverter : QueryStringConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
        {
            return (type == typeof(InputData)) || base.CanConvert(type);
        }
        public override object ConvertStringToValue(string parameter, Type parameterType)
        {
            if (parameterType == typeof(InputData))
            {
                string[] parts = parameter.Split(',');
                return new InputData { FirstName = parts[0], LastName = parts[1] };
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ConvertStringToValue(parameter, parameterType);
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
    {
        protected override QueryStringConverter GetQueryStringConverter(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            return new MyQueryStringConverter();
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new MyWebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/InsertData?param1=John,Doe"));

        client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        Console.WriteLine(client.UploadString(baseAddress + "/InsertData", "{\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\"}"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a custom QueryStringConverter to a webHttpBehaviour already defined in Web.config?

Comment: No, you need a new class for that. You can expose that class in config if you want, though - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx for details.

Comment: Your [personal displeasure with configuration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx) helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Passing a class (data contract) is only possible with POST or PUT request (`WebInvoke`). GET request allows only simple types where each must be part of `UriTemplate` to be mapped to parameter in the method.

Comment: I tried using webinvoke with post method. Still its not working. here is my code ************ [OperationContract] [WebInvoke(UriTemplate= "/InsertData/param1",Method="POST")] string saveData(inputData param1); Here is how I am passing values to WCF service http://localhost:64475/RESTService1.svc/insertData/1004,120Jackson%20blvd,Newyork,ny,10001,Bronx in Browser

Comment: The class must be in request's body. Not in URL.

Comment: is it possible, can you provide some code or example. Thanks for ur time